# How to find out Avro schema from binary data that comes in via Spark Streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, avro

I set up a Spark-Streaming pipeline that gets measuring data via Kafka. This data was serialized using Avro. The data can be of two types - `EquidistantData` and `DiscreteData`. I created these using an `avdl` file and the `sbt-avrohugger` plugin. I use the variant that generates Scala case classes that inherit from `SpecificRecord`.

In my receiving application, I can get the two schemas by querying `EquidistantData.SCHEMA$` and `DiscreteData.SCHEMA$`.

Now, my Kafka stream gives me RDDs whose value class is `Array[Byte]`. So far so good.

How can I find out from the byte array which schema was used when serializing it, i.e., whether to use `EquidistantData.SCHEMA$` or `DiscreteData.SCHEMA$`?

I thought of sending an appropriate info in the message key. Currently, I don't use the message key. Would this be a feasible way or can I get the schema somehow from the serialized byte array I received?

### Followup:

Another possibility would be to use separate topics for discrete and equidistant data. Would this be feasible?

Comment: Both options that you've mentioned will work. One thing to remember is that Kafka uses the message key to partition the data into partitions of a given topic (using MurmurHash), so if you only use the schema name you'll be creating a bias based on which data gets sent more.

Comment: I think it is best to keep different types of data on different topics. it is possible to read multiple topics in the same streaming app though I never did that.

Comment: @TalJoffe Definitely possible. All you need to do is pass multiple topics into `createDStream` or `createStream`.

Comment: Okay, I will then use different topics for the different types.